# Excel - Compare two tabs. Move matches to one tab and others to another tab

Tags: excel

Im looking for a way of taking a "Policy number" from Tab B column A and comparing it a list of "Policy numbers" on Tab A Column A.

If found copy row to Tab C and if not copy row to Tab D

The column headers are

```
Policy#   Date   Amount   Carrier company
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Public Sub CopyRows()

    Dim ewbT As Workbook: Set ewbT = ThisWorkbook ' Change ewbT to target Workbook, maybe ActiveWorkbook
    Dim ewsA As Worksheet: Set ewsA = ewbT.Worksheets("A")
    Dim ewsB As Worksheet: Set ewsB = ewbT.Worksheets("B")
    Dim ewsC As Worksheet: Set ewsC = ewbT.Worksheets("C")
    Dim ewsD As Worksheet: Set ewsD = ewbT.Worksheets("D")

    Dim dctPolicy As Dictionary: Set dctPolicy = New Dictionary
    Dim r As Long: For r = 2 To ewsA.UsedRange.Rows.Count ' Change 2 to first row of data
        dctPolicy.Add ewsA.Cells(r, 1).Value, 0
    Next r

    For r = 2 To ewsB.UsedRange.Rows.Count ' Change 2 to first row of data
        Dim varTemp() As Variant: ReDim varTemp(0 To 0, 0 To 3)
        varTemp = ewsB.Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value
        Dim ewsT As Worksheet: Set ewsT = ewsC
        If dctPolicy.Exists(ewsB.Cells(r, 1).Value) = False Then
            Set ewsT = ewsD
        End If
        ewsT.Cells(ewsC.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value = varTemp
    Next r

End Sub
```

And please note that you need Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime enabled.